# How can I pass a system properties file to GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

Is there a system property or a program argument that I can use to pass the name of a properties file to GWT, to tell GWT to load these into the system properties?

I'm trying to change something like this:

```
com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell -Dsysprop1=value1 -Dsysprop2=value2 ...
```

to something like this:

```
com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell -Dgwt.system.properties=/my/properties/file ...
```

The motivation is to be able to change easily between sets of properties according the runtime environment, for example so that I can have `dev.properties` and `prod.properties` property without having to set the properties individually on the startup command.

---

Aside: there are two other options that will work, but which I'd like to avoid for now:

- adding a layer of indirection through which to pick up all of the system properties (because this will be a pain to retrofit)
- adding a bootstrapper to load the property set before delegating everything GWT (because I'm lazy, though this might be a reasonable longer term option if GWT doesn't support this out of the box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great example of how to do this using GWT Generators [here](http://markmail.org/message/xly5wiftslf23k3w).

Comment: Interesting. If I understand correctly, that boils down to generating a `PropertyMap` class dynamically that populates the properties on creation. Seems slightly awkward to have to write code-generating code to do this, but I suppose that can be templated away.